# BaggageField value returns null after update

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I have the following Spring Cloud Sleuth configuration:

`application.yml` file:

```
  sleuth:
    baggage:
      remote-fields: userId
      correlation-fields: userId
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SleuthConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public BaggageField userIdBaggageField() {
        return BaggageField.create("userId");
    }

    @Bean
    public CurrentTraceContext.ScopeDecorator mdcScopeDecorator() {
        return MDCScopeDecorator.newBuilder()
            .clear()
            .add(CorrelationScopeConfig.SingleCorrelationField
                .newBuilder(userIdBaggageField())
                .flushOnUpdate()
                .build())
            .build();
    }
}
```

When updating the BaggageField in the controller, the `getValue()` method always returns null, although I configured the corresponding BaggageField to flush on update (`.flushOnupdate()` [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/project-features.html#features-baggage)):

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
static class SampleController {

    private final BaggageField userIdBaggageField;

    SampleController(BaggageField userIdBaggageField) {
        this.userIdBaggageField = userIdBaggageField;
    }

    @GetMapping("/sample")
    public void periodes(@RequestParam String userId) {
        log.info("Setting BaggageField to {}", userId);
        this.userIdBaggageField.updateValue(userId);
        log.info("BaggageField value {}", this.userIdBaggageField.getValue());
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
Setting BaggageField to 1234
BaggageField value null
```

What did I possibly miss?

Thanks.

Comment: `updateValue(String value)` method is returning a boolean, apparently it's failing to update the value, maybe because the currentTraceContext is null, try to get the traceContext yourself and use this `this.userIdBaggageField.updateValue(context, value)` , And check the returned boolean of it to make sure the value was updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After debugging, I found that the issue was caused by a custom propagator. The `updateValue(String value)` method returns false due to this configuration. I will answer my question.

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID I am facing a similar issue where currentTraceContext is always null, any pointers as to why that may be happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: @Dfarrelly Can you show a bit of your code ? that could help to detect the reason.

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID I made another post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76226277/brave-baggage-not-working-after-switching-from-spring-cloud-sleuth-to-micrometer if you can take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to a configured custom propagator interfering with default baggage propagation.

Removing it fixes this issue.